# Install a downloaded apk

Tags: android, permissions, kotlin, apk

Android 6.0.1 (API 23)

Try to add autoupdate to my app and get strange thing:

1. Download file into

   ```
   val fileDownloaded = File(context.filesDir, "update.apk")
   ```
2. Then try to install the apk with intent

   ```
   val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, fileUri)
   intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true)
   intent.setDataAndType(fileUri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive")
   intent.flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK or 
           Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
           intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION)
           startActivity(intent)
   ```
3. Manifest's permissions

   ```
    android.permission.INTERNET
    android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
    android.permission.REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES
   ```
4. Have the error "There was a problem parsing the package" and logcat messages:

Unable to open '/data/user/0/com.testapp.android.demo/files/update.apk': **Permission denied**
03-11 12:52:18.815 3330-3330/com.android.packageinstaller W/zipro: Error opening archive /data/user/0/com.testapp.android.demo/files/update.apk: I/O Error
03-11 12:52:18.815 3330-3330/com.android.packageinstaller D/asset: failed to open Zip archive '/data/user/0/com.testapp.android.demo/files/update.apk'
03-11 12:52:18.815 3330-3330/com.android.packageinstaller W/PackageInstaller: Parse error when parsing manifest. Discontinuing installation

Can't get what permissions i must have...

On android API >=24, through FileProvider, all works well. The problem is only on a device with lower api

Could anyone give me idea what is wrong and how fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing a `File` pointing to [internal storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/13/storage-situation-internal-storage.html). Third-party apps, such as the package installer, have no rights to this location. Download the APK to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/11/14/storage-situation-external-storage.html) on older devices.

Comment: Thanks a lot. sometimes everything is easier than it seems